# displaying toast in conditional statements in android

Tags: android, sql-server, toast

i have created an app which insert data to sql server. i made column NAME as unique key.
i want that if i enter same name by edittext to insert...it should give a toast message.
but it's not happening. i cann't understand where i have made error.
in connection to server there is no problem. the only thing is i have to display Toast msg if i entered same name again.
my code is.......

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String myloc=loc.getText().toString();
                    String myname=name.getText().toString();
                    String myphone=phone.getText().toString();
                    initilize();
                    ResultSet rs;
                     try{
                    Statement statement=connect.createStatement();
                    rs=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM FORM1");
                     List<Map<String,String>>data=null;
                     data=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
                     while(rs.next()){
                         Map<String,String>datanum=new HashMap<String,String>();
                         datanum.put("a", rs.getString("NAME"));
                         data.add(datanum);
                     }
                     if(data.contains(myname)){
                     Toast.makeText(c, myname+" Already stored: please choose different one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     }
                     else{
                        insert(myname,myphone,myloc); 
                     }
                     }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage()); 
                         }


                }
```

plzz guys...help me someone...

Comment: Are the records being inserted into database using this code ?

Comment: Where did you get the `c` context variable?

Comment: i declare Context c as global

Comment: yes.....data are inserted

Comment: Instead use getBaseContext() or getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 0):

With `data.contains(myname)` you are trying to check if there is `myname` of type String in your `data` varible, but, in fact, your `data` have type `List<Map<String,String>>`, so when you are invoking `contains(Object object)` method passing a String, you are performing `equals` operation between `Map<String,String>` and `String`, which clearly would always result `false`. So I would suggest you either write something like this

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()) {
    data.add(rs.getString("NAME"));
}
 if(data.contains(myname)){
     Toast.makeText(c, myname+" Already stored: please choose different one", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

or there is a better way, just change your query to `SELECT * FROM FORM1 WHERE NAME = myname` and check if your result set is empty.